# Is there a way to randomly subtract a percentage from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let asume that we have a numpy array that contains a lot of floating numbers.Speaking of which i want to randomly remove from this numpy array a persentage of 5%, is there any way to do this ?
Lets  say we have this array :

```
4.0
5.0
4.0
4.0
5.0
4.0
4.0
5.0
1.0
5.0
```

Comment: Those are not integers...

Comment: @dawg it was a typing mistake

Answer (score 2):

One way is, you can take random `95% data`

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,8,9,2,3,6]) 
numbers = np.random.choice(arr, int(len(arr)*0.95) ) 

print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
print(np.random.permutation(arr)[:int(arr.size*0.95)])
```

Selects the first 95% (rounded down with int()) from a permutation of the array.